# How to make two variable always the same in flex?

Tags: flash, flex3

```
private var nsPlay : NetStream = main.media.nsPlay;
```

When `nsPlay` changes,`main.media.nsPlay` should change accordingly;vice versa.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making nsPlay and main.media.nsPlay public variables? This may still not work, but it's worth a try. My understanding of variable assignment suggests that it should work as you've done it.

Alternatively if they are referring to the same object in memory, why not hold them as a single public variable  (or getter/setter) in a seperate class, which both main.media and this one refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can sent bindable on both the variables and assign one equals the other. Then if any one changes, the other changes, accordingly.